# Vim: Open new file with existing vim in new window

Tags: vim

Here is the first way which works perfectly. I can open new file with existing vim through cmdline with command below, that file will, as expected, be opened in a new window.

```
gvim --remote <filename>
```

However, problem comes up with the other way. When I open windows explorer, right click a file, and choose 'open with existing vim', that file will be opened in the window where I'm editing another file.
Worse still, I'm using Nerdtree at the moment; the Nerdtree window is always used to display the new file, which is definitely intolerable.

Comment: Didn't you try tabs?

Comment: You could simply "open" files from Vim itself, like we all do.

Comment: @romainl You are right. I do that in most cases. But sometimes when I use explorer to find my files, I don't want to open files by typing a long path, since I can easily right click on it and open it.

Comment: @SibiCoder If it can automatically open in new tab, I think it's a perfect solution as well. But I don't know how to make it work that way.

Comment: ``gvim --remote-tab <file>`` for fresh new tab.

Comment: https://github.com/jistr/vim-nerdtree-tabs .Use this instead